# Distribution Convergence of Sequence of Functions

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, distribution-theory

> Consider the sequence of functions
>       \begin{align*}
>     f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
>         0 & x \leq -\tfrac{1}{n}
>         \\[0.5em]
>         nx+1 & x \in (-\tfrac{1}{n},0)
>         \\[0.5em]
>         1 & x\geq 0
>     \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
>       Show by the definition of a distribution that $f_n\rightarrow H$ in the sense of distributions where $H$ is the Heaviside function.

I feel like it would be easier to show that $f_n-H\rightarrow 0$ in the sense of distributions, but I'm not sure how to go from here.

Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to show that $\int_0^{\infty} \phi (x) dx+\int_{-1/n}^{0} (1+nx) \phi (x)dx \to \int_0^{\infty} \phi (x) dx$ for every test function $\phi$. So it suffices to show that $\int_{-1/n}^{0} (1+nx) \phi (x)dx \to 0$. Use the fact that $|1+nx| \leq 1$ and $\phi$ is integrable. So DCT finishes the proof.

Comment: could you elaborate further?

also, i'm assuming DCT is the Distribution Convergence Theorem

Comment: $|\int_{-1/n}^{0} (1+nx) \phi (x)dx| \leq \int_{-1/n}^{0}  |\phi (x)| dx $. For any integrable function $\phi$, $\int_A \phi (x)| dx \to 0$ as $mu (A) \to 0$. @nickoba